# "Segmentation Fault" en Lista Doblemente Enlazada

Tags: c, lista, punteros

Espero puedan ayudarme a visualizar el error en el siguiente código.

He estado estudiando últimamente todos los tipos de listas. En este programa me centro en la inserción de un elemento al inicio de una lista DOBLEMENTE ENLAZADA. Como apenas empecé a estudiar ese tipo de listas, inicié realizando algo sencillo.

El problema es que al momento de ejecutar el programa mediante GDB, en el CMD me aparece una advertencia diciendo que el programa presenta un SEGMENTATIO FAULT justamente en la función que realiza la inserción a la lista.

El código se muestra a continuación.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct elementos
{
    int dato;
    struct elementos *anterior;
    struct elementos *siguiente;
};
typedef struct elementos Nodo;
void insertarElemento(Nodo **cabeza, int x);
void mostrarElementos(Nodo * cabeza);
int main()
{
    Nodo *primero = NULL;

    insertarElemento(&primero, 45);
    mostrarElementos(primero);
    return 0;
}

void insertarElemento(Nodo **cabeza, int x)
{
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevo_nodo -> dato = x;
    nuevo_nodo -> siguiente = *cabeza;
    nuevo_nodo -> anterior = NULL;
    (*cabeza) -> anterior = nuevo_nodo;
    *cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
}

void mostrarElementos(Nodo *cabeza)
{
    while(cabeza != NULL)
    {
        printf("%8d", cabeza -> dato);
        cabeza = cabeza -> siguiente;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void insertarElemento(Nodo **cabeza, int x)
{
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevo_nodo -> dato = x;
    nuevo_nodo -> siguiente = *cabeza;
    nuevo_nodo -> anterior = NULL;
    (*cabeza) -> anterior = nuevo_nodo; // <<---
    *cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
}
```

Si la lista está vacía, `(*cabeza)->anterior`  es una operación no válida... te falta un condicional:

```
if( NULL != cabeza )
  (*cabeza)->anterior = nuevo_nodo;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había notado esa parte.